# Http polling and conditional logic with rxjs in angular project

Tags: angular, rxjs, observable

I am in the early phases of an Angular 4 project trying to create a client for my http services. These services can return one of two things:

1. The actual desired json response from the service with an http status of 200, or
2. A guid which represents a job token with which I can poll for status of the long-running job, and an http status of 202.

When the service returns a 200 status, I want to just return its json content directly, so that's easy enough.

When the result status is a 202, I then want to poll a separate url with that token and receive a json object with status info.  When that status info indicates completion, I want to then make a request to a final url that will return the output.

I'm not sure how to handle the conditional logic that I need within the request. I suspect I could use `repeatWhen` to monitor the result of the polling request, but I'm having trouble figuring out how to use it.

```
http.request('/some/longrunning/job')
    .flatMap((resp: Response) => {
        if (resp.status !== 202)
            return Observable.of(resp);

        var job_token = resp.json().token;
        return http.get('/jobstatus/' + job_token)
            // result from this endpoint is a json object that looks something
            // like { status: 'running' } or { status: 'complete' }
            .repeatWhen(function (polling_resp: Observable<Response>) {
                // How do I use polling_resp here to look at my http response?
                // Do I need to explicitly subscribe to it? And if so,
                // how then do I inspect the response and return the
                // appropriate value to indicate whether or not to
                // resubscribe via the repeatWhen?
            });
    });
```

Can someone give me some hints on how to use logic in the `repeatWhen`? I haven't seen any examples that use content from the observable itself to decide whether to resubscribe.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think you are looking for something more like this:

```
http.request('/some/longrunning/job')
    .flatMap((resp: Response) => {
      if (resp.status !== 202)
          return Observable.of(resp);
      const token = resp.json().token;

      return http.get(`/jobstatus/${token}`)

        // You can use repeatWhen if you need more nuanced logic for
        // how many times you want this to repeat, and how it should 
        // space out repeat attempts.
        // This is just an example that guarantees at least 1 second between
        // poll attempts so as to not overload the server
        .repeatWhen(c => c.debounceTime(1000))

        // Ignore values until you have completed
        .skipWhile(resp => resp.json().status !== 'completed')

        // At this point you can stop the polling
        .take(1)

        // You don't actually care about the value of the response
        // just that it has "completed" this maps that response to the
        // call to fetch the result status.
        .flatMapTo(http.get(`/jobresult/${token}`))

    });
```

Essentially your first conditional is correct, the second part you need to kick off the request and continually repeat it, the `skipWhile` portion will inspect the results and will not propagate them until the status is marked as complete, you can then use `flatMapTo` to convert that resulting message directly into another API request to get the *actual* result which then gets propagated.